# Combine mod_rewrite rules for Craft CMS 3 with cache busting

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

My Craft CMS 3 project has the following rewrite_rule in the `/web` `.htaccess`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Trying to implement cache busting has described here however struggling to combine the existing and proposed rewrite_rules. 
https://nystudio107.com/blog/simple-static-asset-versioning

This is the cache busting rule I need to add.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?\/)*?([a-z\.\-]+)(\d+)\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|js|png|svgz?|webp|webmanifest)$ $1$2$4 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it, let me find some code to propose an answer.

Comment: Checkout the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I'm now using to solve this issue. Hope it helps someone.

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*?\/)*?([a-z\.\-]+)(\d+)\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|js|png|svgz?|webp|webmanifest)$ $1$2$4 [NC]

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,NC]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Port} !=443
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>

# Example to cache images and CSS files
# adjust and extend to your needs
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  #  images expire after 1 week
  <filesMatch ".(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|pdf|svg|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
  </filesMatch>
  # CSS expires after 1 week
  <filesMatch ".(css|js|woff2)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```